# PHPunit Testing for validating errors - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpunit

I have a contact form with name,email,message field and i had controller that validates some input:

I have a test that verifies this to be happening:

```
<?php 
    public function testContactFormValidationFields()
{
        $this->visit('/contact')
            ->type('', 'name')
            ->type('', 'email')
            ->type('', 'message')
            ->press('Send message')
            ->see('Sorry, there were some errors sending your message:')
            ->see('The name field is required.')
            ->see('The email field is required.')
            ->see('The message field is required.')
            ->seePageIs('/contact');     
}
?>
```

And got the exception in the terminal like below:

```
1) LoggedOutFormTest::testContactFormValidationFields
ErrorException: Declaration of Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\Constraints\PageCon
straint::fail() should be compatible with PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint::fail($ot
her, $description, PHPUnit_Framework_ComparisonFailure $comparisonFailure = NULL
)

D:\xampp\htdocs\phpunit-test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Tes
ting\Constraints\PageConstraint.php:114
D:\xampp\htdocs\phpunit-test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Tes
ting\Constraints\HasSource.php:6
D:\xampp\htdocs\phpunit-test\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Tes
ting\Concerns\InteractsWithPages.php:263
D:\xampp\htdocs\phpunit-test\tests\myproject\LoggedOutFormTest.php:27
←[37;41m                                   ←[0m
←[37;41mFAILURES!                          ←[0m
←[37;41mTests: 1, Assertions: 3, Errors: 1.←[0m
```